# oracle sql update with sub select

Tags: oracle

I want to update 1 field of the last 2 rows of a table. So I need a subquery.
Both sql works - how can I combine these 2 SQL commands?

select command (works, last 2 rows):

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from mytable WHERE id='62741' ORDER BY lfdnr DESC) mytable2 WHERE rownum <= 2;
```

Result:

```
 LFDNR ID                   M2            
361782 62741                8,5             
361774 62741                8,6
```

Update (?, exists, in, merge ?)

```
UPDATE mytable set m2='8,4' WHERE EXISTS (select * from mytable WHERE id='62741' and rownum <=2 ORDER BY lfdnr DESC);
```

Result:

Fehlerbericht -
SQL-Fehler: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:
*Action:

Thank you for helping me!
Michael

Comment: I think there is a problem with ORDER BY ...?!?

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result; also, instead of adding comments, editing your question is a better way; in this way the question will be complete and self-explanatory, with no need to read comments to give an answer

Comment: You are already using a subquery. What actually you wanted to do. Are you looking for some joins or correlated queries

Comment: I want to update the last 2 rows, field M2 to new value '8,4'. But my combination of UPDATE and SELECT doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rowid` pseudocolumn:

```
update mytable set m2 = '8, 4' 
  where rowid in (select rowid 
    from (
      select rowid, row_number() over (order by lfdnr desc) rn
        from mytable where id = '62741') 
    where rn <= 2 )
```

Test:

```
create table mytable (id varchar2(5), lfdnr number(5), m2 varchar2(10));
insert into mytable values ('62705', 1, 'abc');
insert into mytable values ('62741', 2, 'xyz');
insert into mytable values ('62741', 3, 'qwe');
insert into mytable values ('62741', 4, 'rty');

ID    LFDNR  M2
----- ------ ----------
62705      1 abc
62741      2 xyz
62741      3 8, 4
62741      4 8, 4
```

Comment: great! Thank you.